# Excel how to: compare values, find the same, compare their adjacent values, find the bigger and return this number +1 at another sheet

Tags: excel, compare, addition

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dRVb.jpg)I am working at Excel.
I have a value (letters) in a cell and i would like to:
find similar values of another column in another sheet.
Then i would like to compare the values of this "group" which are located at the next column.
Then i would like to find the bigger and add to it +1.
Finally I would like to write the result in a cell in the initial sheet.
Could you please help me?

[how my sheets look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dRVb.jpg)

Comment: It should be do-able but I'm not sure what you mean by 'similar'? Can you post some sample data plz and say what you've tried?

Comment: Hello,thank you a lot for your answer.

Comment: In the above post i just included a picture of the sheets. So from the Sheet 1 i want to take the value from D11 and compare it to the column B from the Sheet 2. Then I want to count how many times it appears and return a value [count+1] at E11 from the sheet 1.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly it should just be a COUNTIF

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!B2:B6,D11)+1
```

placed in Sheet1 E11.

If you wanted to do it by finding the largest number in Sheet2 C2:C6 with the same group of letters, the neatest way to do it is using AGGREGATE

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,Sheet2!C2:C6/(Sheet2!B2:B6=D11),1)+1
```